# Proof of $157$ Kelley's theorem in the appendix

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The theorem $157$ (p. no $275$) claims:

> If $\alpha$ is an ordinal number and $x\subset \alpha$, then $\mbox{card } x \leq \alpha$.

To prove that he mentions two previous result:

> **Theorem $94$.** If $X$ is a well-ordered class, $Y\subset X$ is a section (a segment) and $f:Y\rightarrow X$ is an order-preserving map, then for each $y \in Y$ is false that $f(y)<y$.
>
> **Theorem $99$.** If $\mathcal R$ well-orders $X$ and $\mathcal S$ well-orders $Y$, then there is a function $f$ which is $\mathcal R$-$\mathcal S$ order preserving in $X$ and $Y$ and such that either $\mbox{dom }f=X$ or $\mbox{im }f = Y$.

Moreover, there one important result that I think can help us:

> If $X,Y$ are two well-ordered classes and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an order-preserving function, then $f$ is injective and $f^{-1}$ is order-preserving.

Now, I write the proof **literally** as Kelleys does it:

''By theorem $99$ there is a $1-1$ function $f$ which is $\mathcal E$- (the oreder relation for ordinals) order preserving and such that $\mbox{dom }f = x$ or $\mbox{im }f=\mathcal O$ (the class of all ordinals). Since $X$ is a set and $\mathcal O$ is not, then $\mbox{dom }f = x$. By Theorem $94$, $f(u)\leq \alpha$ for all $u$ in $x$, and consequently $x$ is equivalent to an ordinal less than or equal to $\alpha$''.

EDIT:

hanks to some comments of @CarlMummert I have only one question:

> > I can't see how he uses Theorem $94$. It is true that $\alpha$ and $\mbox{im }f$ are sections, but I can't see how from that fact he claims that $f(u)\in\alpha$ for all $u\in x$.

I have also tried to prove the theorem on my own. Here is the proof. I would like you to ckeck it, because a have a question:

Using theorem 99 it is clear that $\mbox{dom }f=x$. By the same theorem $\mbox{im }f\subset\mathcal O$ is a section (initial sectment) and thus, by a previous result, an ordinal number. Call it $\beta$. What I want to show know is that $\beta\leq \alpha$, because then we would have an equivalence $\tilde f:x\rightarrow \mbox{im }f$ between $x$ and an ordinal $\beta$ less or equal than $\alpha$. Hence by the definition of cardinal number the theorem follows.

Because $f(\gamma)$ is an ordinal for every $\gamma\in x$, by trichotomity of $\in$:

$$ f(\gamma)<\alpha \quad \text{or} \quad \alpha<f(\gamma) \quad \text{or} \quad f(\gamma)=\alpha .$$

Suppose there is a $\gamma\in x$ such that $\alpha\in f(\gamma)$. By the above claim, I know $f^{-1}$ is order-preserving, so I would have

$$ f^{-1}(\alpha)\in\gamma \in\alpha. $$

But $\beta$ was a section of $\mathcal O$, so by theorem 94 the above is impossible, which means there is no such a $\gamma$. The same happens if I suppose $\gamma\in x$ such that $f(\gamma)=\alpha$. Hence $\mbox{im }f \subset\alpha$ and also $\mbox{im }f \in\alpha$, as I wanted.

But the problem of my proof is that $\alpha$ is supposed to be in $\mbox{im }f$ and that might not happen, might it? So... is my proof correct? If not, why can solve the problem of $\alpha$?

Thanks

Comment: Theorem 99 is mistated.  Of course if f:X -> Y, then dom f = X by definition.

Comment: Not at all. I mean I suppose he is thinking for example in $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$ for example.

Comment: He is not thinking about real numbers.  He is thinking about well ordered sets which R is not.

Comment: It was just an example to show that sometimes you write $f:X\rightarrow Y$ but $\mbox {Dom }f\neq X$ but only a subset of $X$.

Comment: I have just corrected some little tipos in the Kelley's proof. I hope this allow you to give me satisfactory answer.

Comment: I still do not understand theorem 99.

Comment: I have rewritten theorem 99 exactly as it is in the book. Look at it. I also add an edit with my tried of (incomplete) proof.

Comment: @William Elliot: the lemma says that any two well orderings (one or both of which may be a proper class) are comparable. The proof is to let $f$ send the smallest element of $X$ to the smallest element of $Y$, then the next element to the next element and so on, transfinitely. If we run out of elements of $X$ first, then $\text{dom}(f) = X$ and $f$ may not be surjective. If we run out of elements of $y$ first then $f$ is surjective but its domain may be only a subset of $X$.  (Also, as quoted Theorem 99 does not say "$f\colon X \to Y$")

Comment: I got up this morning thinking exactly the same thing, but I consulted the definition of _order-preserving_ function in another book. For Kelley's, and order-preserving function is such that $\mbox{dom }f $ and $\mbox{im }f$ are both initial segments of $X$ and $Y$ resp. Thanks a lot @Carl Mummert. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @CarlMummert: I was talking about Definition 98.

Comment: I see - there is a difference between "order preserving" and "order preserving in $x$ and $y$". So that resolves everything, because Theorem 99 does say that the domain and range of $f$ are initial segments, although it says it in an obscure way.

Comment: Yes. And when he applies Thm. 99 in Theorem 157, he is assuming $x$ to be an initial segment (which is not said in the statement).

Comment: I don't think that assumption is needed in Theorem 157, and it's not a hypothesis of Theorem 99.  Why do you think he is making that assumption?  At the end of the proof of 157, he does not say $x$ is an ordinal, only that it is equivalent to one (under $f$).  Because of the way the ordinal numbers are defined, there is no difference between being an ordinal number and being an initial segment of a (larger) ordinal number - every initial segment of an ordinal is again an ordinal.

Comment: With all the edits made to the question, it is hard for me to tell what is still being asked. Once you have a chance to think, consider re-writing parts of it, deleting old questions you have figured out. For example, are you still asking about theorem 94? It is used to show that the range of $f$ in Ord does not go past $y$, so that the ordinal that $f$ maps $x$ to is less than or equal to $y$.

Comment: Oh, yes I see what you say. $x$ is in fact an initial segment of $x$. Yes, you're right. That assumption is false. And yes. I think I'm going to delete this question, think about the proof and, perhaps, write another one. Any way, @Carl Mummert thanks for your comments. They help me a lot.

Comment: @Dog_69.  As f:X -> Y has been removed from theorem 99, the correct version makes sense.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: Why? If I say you that for me $f:X\rightarrow Y$ means that $\mbox{dom }f \subseteq X$ and $\mbox{im }f \subseteq Y$, it helps you? I mean, does it also have sense?

Comment: Hi guys. I have edited one last time the question (I promise). If you think it isn't clear I'll delete it and I'll ask a new question. But if you understand it please help me. You can directly answer my question in yellow or help me with my own proof. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dog_69.  No.  Functions are usually not considered to be partial functionx.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: Ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think my proof is right. If $\alpha\notin \mbox{im }f$ we have already finished. Otherwise, must supposed $\alpha\in\mbox{im }f$.